# How do I connect the C++ Wii devkitpro to the internet?

Tags: c++, sockets, wii, devkitpro

I am struggling with my code in devkitpro trying to get this program to connect to the Internet. It says it connects, it gets an IP address.

However, how do I read from the Internet and verify that it is even writing my data to the socket? This is a very tough devkit due to the lack of or quality of the documentation. I need some help on this.

**EDIT**: I'll post the code when asked for it. It is long and needs cleaning up.

Comment: If there's a *lot* of code, you're doing the right thing in not including all of it.  It would be helpful, however, if you could provide a high-level explanation of what you've tried, or possibly code excerpts that you're worried about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The socket code in *devkitPPC/libogc* closely mirrors the *BSD sockets* interface. The main differences are that functions are prefixed with `net_` (`net_socket`, `net_connect`, `net_send`, etc), `net_select()` is not implemented, and in most cases the error codes are *returned from the functions* themselves, *not with errno*.
If you've created a socket and connected it to a remote server, you've probably figured this out already!

> However, how do I read from the Internet and verify that it is even
> writing my data to the socket?

The same way you would on on a PC! Open a connection with `net_socket()` and `net_connect()`, read and write data with `net_send()` and `net_revc()`, call `net_close()` when done.
Check return values from these functions to determine whether the operation succeeded or failed. Most functions *return < 0 when an error has occurred*. You will also have to initialize the Wii network hardware and obtain an IP address first.

> This is a very tough devkit due to the lack of or quality of the
> documentation.

Very true. Some system headers are documented using Doxygen, unfortunately `network.h` isn't. However, as the interface is similar to BSD sockets, most socket tutorials or examples can be applied.

> I'll post the code when asked for it. It is long and needs cleaning
> up.

Post some code and I'll do my best to offer more help.

Comment: I ran debug but it is not reading the entire response. It is reading though. HTTP Is 200 OK. And it detects 404.

Comment: Try making a small test app on the PC that connects and receives some data. Verify that it works correctly. Then replace the socket functions with the devkitPPC/libogc equivalents and test it on the Wii, using the example templates here: http://devkitpro.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=devkitpro/wii-examples;a=tree;f=template;h=5f21fc5378ca14577baed9c5fe68a76ed97b67ff;hb=HEAD

Comment: Okay, Sending all data, And receiving all data. I'm giving up with this project. I'll start a new one that may be doable at some point. The code works, However its the site that i need to access that IS NOT sending accurate data. I could make a proxy, But all that just for a wii app? no thanks, i'll drop the project